# Safari makes weird noises, even when the sound is closed

Tags: safari

My netbook is 1.5 years old and it only happens when Safari is opened. Why it happens? I think that the sounds are coming from my HDD. Should I remove Safari completely? Does it harm my netbook?

Latest Safari (5.0.5) on Windows 7 Starter
Netbook with Intel Atom 1.6 Ghz 1.6 GHz processor and 1 GB ram, 160 GB HDD
Brand: Casper

Comment: (Win|Lose)dows is harming your computer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would be more interested in looking at the resources being taken up by your computer when you run Safari (CPU, memory, etc.). Safari in and of itself does not harm the hardware or software.

See if there is a heavy load on the computer during operation of Safari to verify that the computer isn't straining under a bug or something else getting stuck when it runs.